# passing a single character/multiple character user input from a python function to a C++ function

Tags: python, function, dll, input

I have a C++ .dll function that I am accessing through python 3.2 with the syntax:

```
int Create(char argID)
```

and I am trying to access this function using python. I can access it, but I am confused on why it is telling for '**wrong type**' whenever I try to pass the function an argument.
Python Script:

```
Create.argtypes = [c_char]
Create.restype = c_int
ID = c_char
ID = input("Enter ID:")
Create(ID) #ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

Not sure where I am going wrong or is there a different way to pass a character or characters from the user input? Kindly help.

Cheers.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `raw_input` instead of `input`?

Comment: I am working on python version 3.2. raw_input() is replaced by input().

Comment: Ah. Good to know. Thanks. Sorry I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A c_char is a one-byte value, not a Unicode string. Set `ID = bytes(ID, 'utf8')[0]` (or use a different 8-bit character mapping than 'utf8', such as 'latin-1'). Then you can call `Create(ID)`.

By the way, assigning ID to c_char only gives you another reference to c_char, and then you immediately reassign ID to the returned string from `input`. The only time I see this is when people are working with ctypes. It's like the brain gets stuck in static typing mode.

Comment: By the way I am using ctypes because of the fact that I am accessing a C++ dll from Python. I tried your way and I am not getting any errors, but the Create function is not being executed because ID now has a value(66) instead of a character('B'). Since my C++ function accepts a character, what would you suggest?

Comment: Very helpful information :). Just another question in the same context, how do we do the same for a string of characters? Thanks again for your answer. It works now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. +1 from my side :). You have been really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your Create function accept a single char as argument, not a string.

```
s = input("enter ID:")
c = ctypes.c_char(s[0])
Create(c)
```

Comment: Yes certainly. But I just input one character as an input. Does it read as a string? If so, what is the equivalent command so that it could read a single character?

Comment: I think the ID name implies it is some sort of numeric value converted as a char, then you should use
    `s = int(input("Enter ID"))` 
    `c = ctypes.c_char(chr(s))`
Edit: Formatting is a bitch

Comment: @ Leo: No, it is a single character input and not a numeric value. Something like 'a', 'b' etc.
@MatthieuW: It did not work the way you suggested via the code. Same error again.